# Invoking the function in bash does not give the proper result

Tags: bash, function, invoke

I took  the code from this nice article: https://catonmat.net/tcp-port-scanner-in-bash

It uses the function `scan`. When I copy the code, it doesn't work for me.

I had similar issues with bash functions before and could not find the solution either.

I try to invoke the function this way directly in the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

scan() {
  if [[ -z $1 || -z $2 ]]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 <host> <port, ports, or port-range>"
    return
  fi

  local host=$1
  local ports=()
  case $2 in
    *-*)
      IFS=- read start end <<< "$2"
      for ((port=start; port <= end; port++)); do
        ports+=($port)
      done
      ;;
    *,*)
      IFS=, read -ra ports <<< "$2"
      ;;
    *)
      ports+=($2)
      ;;
  esac

  for port in "${ports[@]}"; do
    alarm 1 "echo >/dev/tcp/$host/$port" &&
      echo "port $port is open" ||
      echo "port $port is closed"
  done
}

scan
```

I also tried `$(scan)` - did not work as well.

The result - it does not want to scan anything ( I think there is something I should run in order to invoke the function - the code seems fine):

```
$ ./scan.sh google.com 22-99
Usage: ./scan.sh <host> <port, ports, or port-range>
$ ./scan.sh scan google.com 22-99
Usage: ./scan.sh <host> <port, ports, or port-range>
```

What am I missing? It is not the first time I've had a similar problem.

---

P.S. As was already suggested, `scan "$1" "$2"` did the job alright. However, now I encountered a similar issue when invoking this function from a different function:

```
function dosmth {
while test $# -gt 0; do
           case "$1" in
                -t)
                    shift
                    scan "$1" "$2"
                    shift
                    ;;
                *)

exit 1
                   ;;
          esac
  done
}

dosmth $1
```

I also tried `dosmth "$1" "$2"` - the issue persists.

Right now `dosmth` function works alright but `scan` has the similar result as before it does not scan anything.

```
$ ./dosmt.sh -t google.com 80
Usage: -t ./dosmt.sh <host> <port, ports, or port-range>
```

---

My solution may help somebody - I changed to:
`dosmth "$1" "$2" "$3"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If function run from a script, you need to pass args from script to the function

```
...
scan "$1" "$2"
```

Same goes when function run from another function, you have to pass args from "parent" function to "child" function.

```
fun1() {
    echo "fun1 $1 $2"
}

fun2() {
    fun1 "$1" "$2"
}

fun2 "$1" "$2"
```

Also it's a good practice to create vars with appropriate names from this args($1, $2, $3 ...) to use in functions.

```
#!/bin/bash
script=$0
host=$1
port_range=$2
ports=()

scan() {
  if [[ -z $host || -z $port_range ]]; then
    echo "Usage: $script <host> <port, ports, or port-range>"
    return
  fi

  case $port_range in
    *-*)
      IFS=- read start end <<< "$port_range"
      for ((port=start; port <= end; port++)); do
        ports+=($port)
      done
      ;;
    *,*)
      IFS=, read -ra ports <<< "$port_range"
      ;;
    *)
      ports+=($port_range)
      ;;
  esac

  for port in "${ports[@]}"; do
    alarm 1 "echo >/dev/tcp/$host/$port" &&
      echo "port $port is open" ||
      echo "port $port is closed"
  done
}

scan
```

Comment: You are my hero. This works right now. Let me amend my post a bit since I got the next similar issue when invoking function in a function. Passing parameters did not help.

Comment: Appreciate your help but passing `dosmth $1 $2` did not work in my second case (I already have  `scan "$1" "$2"` in the second function). I am eager to find a solution.
Also, I don't know why changing $1 and $2 to something else did not work either - it even broke the program.

Comment: These vars $1, $2, ... are spesial. They're not global as other vars set in bash script. Each function has it's own set of args so if you run a function that uses args($1, $2, ...) without options it'll obviously fail or provide undisired result.

Comment: And in your last example you run function `dosmth` with only one option `$1` but function `scan` needs two

Comment: Running like that `dosmth $1 $2` did not solve the issue - it won't scan.
(So I have `scan "$1" "$2"` in one function and  `dosmth "$1" "$2"` is out of the function).

Comment: It's loos stupid, but `dosmth "$1" "$2" "$3"` did the job. I barely have an idea how it works. Where does it take the 3rd parameter? I have not declared $3 anywhere in the code.

Comment: @t7e The third parameter is needed because of these `shift` commands. And if it not set, function will get an empty option. So you basically done this `dosmth "$1" "$2" ""`